# Android Plugin for Eclipse Update Problem

Tags: android

After performing an update to a new version of the Eclipse Android Plugin, it stopped working. There is no Android Tool visible anywhere. The Window/Preferences tool does not show the Android plugin to configure. And yet, it is installed (says the "Eclipse Installation Details").

I tried uninstalling the Plugin, and re-installing, but it still does not show anywhere.

Currently, I try to download a new version of Eclipse (I used 3.4) and restart everything. Hopefully I can continue with the new version. I am so fed up with this kind of errors!

Thanks for any hints,

René

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Then I answer my own question.

After installing the Android Plugin for the new downloaded Eclipse, the Android tools were back.

Remains one problem:

- The auto-proposals (after entering .) take an eternity now. If this continues the feature is unusable, and I will have to find a way to switch it off.

I solved this, see http://androidjava.wordpress.com/.